# How to find the count of users who viewed/used the table in the last 2 weeks in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to get the number of users who have used the particular table or all the tables in any of the DML scripts in teradata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to have enabled Query Logging with OBJECTS to capture this information in the data dictionary (DBC). Typically this data is moved from DBC to a set of historical tables elsewhere on the system for analysis and audit purposes. Check with your DBA team for how they are managing DBQL within your environment.